# How to get names in string?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, path, directory

Get last name of the directory:

```
str = "/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD"
editstr = str.split("/")[-1]
print(editstr)

folderD
```

How do I get all the directories before `folderD` (without the last slash)? E.g:

```
editstr = ???
print(editstr)

/folderA/folderB/folderC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[There is a module for this.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.dirname)

```
>>> import os
>>> s = "/folderA/folderB/folderC/folderD"
>>> os.path.basename(s)
'folderD'
>>> os.path.dirname(s)
'/folderA/folderB/folderC'
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use [`str.rsplit()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
>>> editstr = str.rsplit('/folderD', 1)[0]
>>> print(editstr)
/folderA/folderB/folderC
```